# react-navigation-stack sharing navigationOptions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm trying to use StackNavigator and I want to use the same Navigation throught my other screens.

My config:

- expo version :3.0.10
- "react-navigation": "^4.3.6",
- "react-navigation-stack": "^2.3.10"

In my `Navigation.js`:

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack'
import Step1 from '../Components/Steps/Step1'
import Step2 from '../Components/Steps/Step2'

const StepsStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Step1: {
      screen: Step1,
      navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Etape 1',
    }},
  Step2: {
      screen: Step2,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Step2'
    }
  }
})

export default createAppContainer(StepsStackNavigator)
```

Here is the props I want to share but I want to keep title for each screens

```
 headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.7)'},
 headerTintColor: 'black',
 headerTitleStyle: {fontWeight: 'bold'}
```

Somebody can help me please !

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of how I've got the stack navigator set up currently, your options have been pasted in.

```
const MainStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Step1: {
    screen: Step1,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Etape 1'
    }
  },
  Step2: {
    screen: Step2,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Step2'
    }
  }
}, {
  headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.7)'},
  headerTintColor: 'black',
  headerTitleStyle: {fontWeight: 'bold'}
});

const AppNav = createAppContainer(MainStackNavigator);

export default AppNav;
```

If you have intellisense installed its possible to cmd click on the import of `createStackNavigator` and view the parameters it takes in, specifically the second argument. Cmd clicking any of them will take you to the declaration and show you the available config options.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. But i'm a beginner with JS and react native so i don't understand how  to use it with my navigationOption for Step1 and Step 2

Comment: Updated for clarity, the file at ./routes was just exporting an object

Comment: createStackNavigator is simply a function that takes 2 arguments, the first being an object containing your routes and the second being an object with your navigation options

Comment: Now i understand what you did, the app run and i can navigate throught my screens but when i try your code it don't take the 2 argument which contains the headerStyle, headerTintColor, headerTitleStyle however, "title" in the first argument change